# AngularJS - directive not triggering after model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have calendar app. After initialization everything is working correctly. The problem is after I change my model (month), the directive is not updating for newly created elements.

The view part:

```
<li class="day" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:month.daysInMonth()">    
    <span class="day-number" calendar-day="{{ n }}-{{ month.format('MM-YYYY') }}">{{ n }}</span>
</li>
```

The directive:

```
directive('calendarDay', ['month', function (month) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch(month, function (value) {
           var currentDate = moment(attrs.calendarDay, "DD-MM-YYYY");
           element.text(currentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
       });

    };
}]);
```

The model `month` is a model declared in app as:

```
value('month', moment());
```

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/EEVGG/11/

As you cen see, the month and year part of the code is not changing, while it should because the value in `calendar-day` attribute is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to watch for changes on the scope property 'month' and not the *month* object you defined on the module. To do that, change the *watchExpression* to `'month'` (String):

```
scope.$watch('month', function (value) {
    var currentDate = moment(attrs.calendarDay, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    element.text(currentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
}, true);
```

Also set the watcher to compare changes based on object equality (last argument of `$watch`) because your month object will be the same, only some properties will change. For more information on this check [$watch documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/EEVGG/12/